# Deleted Anaconda directory, now can't use Python3 in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I deleted the Anaconda directory as I haven't been using it, and now in terminal when I type `python3` I get `-bash: //anaconda/bin/python3: No such file or directory`.

I have an installation of python3.6 that's showing when I type `which python3`.  I'd really appreciate any help figuring out how to correct this so that I can access python3 in the terminal once more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash caches name lookups; clear `python3` from that cache:

```
hash -d python3
```

The next time you use `python3` the `PATH` directories are searched again and the result is cached again.

Comment: Thanks Martjin, I've been trying to figure that out for an hour